# Переливающийся текст в андроид

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы в TextView текст переливался разными цветами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял вам нужен TextView с градиентом. Ниже простейший пример TextView с применением линейного градиента:

```
public class GradientTextView extends TextView {

    public GradientTextView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, -1);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public GradientTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (changed) {
            getPaint().setShader(
                    new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.WHITE,
                            Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/gradienttextview.php)